# PyQt5: Enable sorting a particular column in a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a table that contains 3 rows and 2 columns. I am trying to sort the table based on the first column data. When I use the `setSortingEnabled(True)` it enables the sorting for all the columns. I have tried different methods but nothing helped to overcome the issue. Attached is the sample code for reference.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super (Window, self).__init__()
        Window.setGeometry(self, 0, 22, 480, 250)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 5, 460, 200))
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        horHeaders = ["seat", "material"]
        data = [("15","leather"),("18","plastic"),("20","resin")]

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        row_number = 0
        for i in data:
            self.table.insertRow(row_number)
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 0, QTableWidgetItem(i[0]))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 1, QTableWidgetItem(i[1])) 
            row_number += 1 
            print(i)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.table.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.show()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem, could you explain in detail what you want to obtain.

Comment: I want to enable only first header to sort the contents in the table. currently, I can sort using columns 1 and 2. Ascending or descending arrow should be available only for column 1. Sorting should not happen if I click the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to choose which column can be ordered so a workaround would override the mouseReleaseEvent method for the columns of the first column, you should also take into account that this solution has secondary effects such as column movement, column selection complete etc but in this special case the OP doesn't use them.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        index = self.visualIndexAt(event.pos().x())
        logical_index = self.logicalIndex(index)
        if logical_index == 0:
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 22, 480, 250)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.header = HeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.header.setSectionsClickable(True)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeader(self.header)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 5, 460, 200))

        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        horHeaders = ["1", "2", "3"]
        data = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d"), ("e", "f")]
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        row_number = 0
        for i0, i1 in data:
            self.table.insertRow(row_number)
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(i0))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(i1))
            row_number += 1

        self.table.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```